# ANDROID AjaxCallback Retry function

Tags: android, ajax

I am trying to use AjaxCallback Retry function but cant. can any one tell me about parameter of  retry function. if anyone know give me explain how we can use it?

```
aquery.ajax("http://192.168.3.112:2000/login", params, JSONObject.class,
                        new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void callback(String url, JSONObject json , AjaxStatus status) {
                //BODY
          }.retry(retry));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT My answer  just pass number of retry in .retry(int ) parameters

```
aquery.ajax("http://192.168.3.112:2000/login", params, JSONObject.class,
                        new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void callback(String url, JSONObject json , AjaxStatus status) {
                //BODY
          }.retry(3));
```